# How to retreive the hotkey of a function/tool?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, shortcut, operator

I want to print the hotkeys for some tools in the console. How can I retreive the hotkey for let's say the *circle select tool*, or the hotkey for *rotating the viewport* with python?

Note that I do not want to execute those tools. So I guess I need to access the keymap directly, and read the hotkeys from there. But how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have some clue about how each command is executed (i.e. the operator) in order to find its hotkeys, but if you do, it's not too difficult:

```
wm            = bpy.context.window_manager                       # Blender window manager
keymaps_3DV   = wm.keyconfigs['Blender'].keymaps['3D View']      # 3D View hotkeys
circle_keymap = keymaps_3DV.keymap_items['view3d.select_circle'] # Circle select keymap object
main_key      = circle_keymap.type                               # "C" in this case
```

If you want to see if any modifier key is used, or if the ALT / SHIFT / CTRL keys are used, you can access this info this way:

```
modifier_key = circle_keymap.key_modifier   # Is 'NONE' in this case
shift        = circle_keymap.shift          # Is False in this case
ctrl         = circle_keymap.ctrl           # Is False in this case
alt          = circle_keymap.alt            # You've guessed it
```

There's lots of other interesting properties of hotkeys to investigate, but I'll leave it to you.

To see the rotate operator's hotkey, access it thus:

```
circle_keymap = keymaps_3DV.keymap_items['transform.rotate']
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I think this gives me the needed kickstart :)

Comment: @Tiles, had some errors in the code above (wrote this too fast and too early in the morning lol). Have another look at the code if you had trouble earlier.

Comment: Mornings are evil! :D

Thanks for your effort. Mh, to retreive the key somehow works. But it seems that it gets a hardcoded hotkey from somewhere. I have changed the hotkey for Circle select to L, but it still shows C. The hotkey for rotate shows correct though. Interesting results ^^

Comment: The solution is to use wm.keyconfigs['Blender User'] and wm.keyconfigs['Blender Addon'] instead of wm.keyconfigs['Blender']. Then i get the actual hotkeys. Problem solved. Thanks for help and listening :)